An error occurs when writing tests for node:crypto with Vitest
I want to write tests for the following function using Vitest.
import { randomUUID } from "node:crypto";

export const getRandomUUID = (): string => {
  return randomUUID();
}

I wrote the following test code for the above function.
import { beforeEach, describe, expect, it, vi } from "vitest";
import { getRandomUUID } from "./utils";

vi.mock("node:crypto", () => {
  return {
    randomUUID: vi.fn(() => "mock-uuid"),
  };
});

describe("getRandomUUID", () => {
  it("mock-uuid", () => {
    const uuid = getRandomUUID();

    expect(uuid).toBe("mock-uuid");
  });
});

Then, the following error occurred.

Error: [vitest] No "default" export is defined on the "node:crypto" mock. Did you forget to return it from "vi.mock"?
If you need to partially mock a module, you can use "importOriginal" helper inside:

Therefore, I rewrote the mock part as follows.
vi.mock("node:crypto", async () => {
  const actual = await vi.importActual<typeof import("node:crypto")>("node:crypto");
  return {
    ...actual,
    randomUUID: vi.fn(() => "mock-uuid"),
  };
});

Then, the following error occurred.

AssertionError: expected '5cedbc46-aaaf-40f3-9943-fbaedb9da36b' to be 'mock-uuid' // Object.is equality

I believe this is an AssertionError caused by not properly mocking randomUUID, but I am unsure how to resolve it and would like your guidance.

When you use vi.importActual to preserve the real implementation of node:crypto and add a mock for randomUUID, the mock might not be properly overriding the actual randomUUID in the environment where your test runs.  Mock node:crypto completely so that  randomUUID is replaced everywhere it is used.
